# $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx}{(1+x)(1+2x)...(1+nx)}$ convergence domain.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Problem**: Study the absolute and conditional convergence domain of the series: $$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx}{(1+x)(1+2x)...(1+nx)}$$
>   **1)** for $0\leqslant x\leqslant \epsilon$,$\epsilon>0$ and **2)** $\epsilon\leqslant x<+\infty$.

I chose to apply the Alambert critera:$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(n+1)x}{(1+x)(1+2x)...(1+(n+1)x)}}{\frac{nx}{(1+x)(1+2x)...(1+nx)}}=\lim{n\to\infty}\frac{nx+x}{nx+n^2x^2+nx^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}=\frac{x+\frac{x}{n}}{x+nx^2+x^2}=0$

**Question**:

Is my attempt right? Because if it is. Why would the author ask the question for different convergence domain("1) for $0\leqslant x\leqslant \epsilon$,$\epsilon>0$ and 2) $\epsilon\leqslant x<+\infty$")?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If that's the actual problem, your proof is fine. Something tells me that's not the problem however. I sense that the real question is about uniform convergence.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for the observation. I guess you are right. However I have never dealt with uniform convergence on series. What are you thinking? I would be grateful if you formalized your statement.

Comment: You can find the definition online. It's exactly what you think it should be.